# Unable to reference system.runtime unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, reference

So I am coding a multiplayer game in unity with smartfoxserver, I was trying to build a script that would connect my client to my server but I got the the error:

`"The type 'System.Object' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'System.Runtime, Version=4.0.10.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'.`

This line was displayed over `public SmartFox _client;`

I attempted to go the the solutions panel and add a reference to `System.Runtime`, but I could not find it, the closest I was able to find was System.Runtime.Serialization.

Code is pasted down below, thanks in advance.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using Sfs2X;
using Sfs2X.Core;
using Sfs2X.Requests;
using Sfs2X.Entities;

public class Client : MonoBehaviour {


private string host="localhost"; 
private int port= 9933; 


public SmartFox _client;

// Use this for initialization
void Start () {
    _client = new SmartFox ();
    _client.ThreadSafeMode = true;
    _client.AddEventListener (SFSEvent.CONNECTION, OnConnection);
    Connect();      
}

// Update is called once per frame
void FixedUpdate () {

    _client.ProcessEvents ();

}
public void Connect(){
    _client.Connect (host, port);
}

public void OnConnection(BaseEvent _event){
    if ((bool)_event.Params ["success"]) {
        Debug.Log("Successfully connected to server");

    } else { Debug.Log("Failed to connect to server")
        //failed

    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a "using System" statement at the top of the file.